# Adjacent means side-by-side. What's the word for behind-one-another?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

Example: rows 9 and 10 in the theatre are ??? rows.

Alternatively: rows 9 an 10 are ???-ly adjacent (while seats B and C are *laterally* adjacent).

There are words like *subsequent*, *consecutive*, etc., which have a somewhat temporal flavour, or at the very least hint at a sequential context (both are cognates of *sequor*, after all). But what's a good word choice for a strictly spatial context: an object behind/in front of another?

**Clarification:** I am a quasi-native speaker specifically curious as to why such a word seems so elusive, and equally as interested whether such a word exists in *other* languages. If there's no such thing, I'll accept that as an answer too.

Comment: And why not *sequential*?

Comment: @bib I think the OP means that sequential implies a logic (numerical or other)

Comment: What if there is no sequence? Maybe theatre rows are a bad example; say you only have two objects?

Comment: Note also that *posterior to* and *anterior to* fit the bill perfectly, except that they're uni-directional. I'm looking for a word to specify the objects' *relationship* in space.

Comment: Er, who says *adjacent* means side-by-side and not just 'next to one another' as theatre rows are?

Comment: You can certainly say the rows are adjacent to each other from the point of view of the aisles...

Comment: But *behind* and *in front of*, too, are not merely spatial but ordered according to some visual perspective. If you are speaking of an unordered relationship *adjacent* works just dandy.

Comment: @TimLymington on second thought, you're right; I wasn't being fair to *adjacent*. But does that mean that with *adjacent* covering all types of neighbour-neighbour relationships, there is no specific word indicating the opposite of a lateral orientation?

Comment: How 'bout *neighboring*?

Comment: Not everything has sides, so not everything can be adjacent. Check out [Chuck Fillmore on "Space"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf), from the [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).

Comment: @StoneyB Good point. I should clarify that I'm looking for the relationship along that very front-back axis (as opposed to the left-right axis), assuming such axes are reasonably well defined (as they are in a theatre). The opposite of "lateral" would be a good start.

Comment: A theater is usually a rectangle or square shape (space). Seats are set out in horizontal rows, one after the other. In the rows, seats are adjacent to each other. The rows are horizontal to one another, they come: one after another.

Comment: Another interesting option is "sagittally", but I've never heard it used outside of anatomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the rows are stacked or ordered front to back.

Comment: *Stacked* clearly lies along the vertical axis. Although depending on the theatre, that might work just fine to describe the rows.

Comment: I will accept this answer because it will help me with future theatre reservations, although it is not 100% spot on.

Answer (score 2):

If this were a spreadsheet, you'd refer to that direction as *columns* as opposed to *rows*.

If you are talking about a theatre row, then you would just say the *row behind*.

If you are speaking of people, then you could use *in line*, or *in a column* to describe this positioning.

Comment: Those are all good alternatives in specific situations, but I was specifically interested whether a single word to describe this positioning exists. What if you are describing three theatre rows, not two? If everybody agrees that there is no such word, that's okay too.

Comment: @sebastian_k Two rows behind.  Three rows behind.  I don't know that there is a one size fits all here.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard **tandem** used when talking about parking spaces that are one in front of the other.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! (Although I don't think it fits the bill in the general case, as it really seems to be limited to one-behind-the-other parking space pairs specifically when one end is walled off.)

Comment: Rather than "tandem", I have come across (and occasionally use) the expression "in tandem" to describe things which are one after the other, though I am unable to give any origin for it. And there is the tandem bicycle, as distinct from the sociable or side-by-side bicycle.

Answer (score 1):

**Back-to-back** looks like a good fit as a single word. It can mean facing in opposite directions too but colloquially it has the sense of *consecutive* as well, although mainly for abstract concepts like games, shifts, interviews etc.

> *informal* consecutive - *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/back-to-back)*

Apparently, it is a term referring to the spacing between the seats in auditorium design also:

> Back to Back Spacing: 
> Sometimes referred to as row spacing, back to back: this is the total space allocated for each row of chairs. It is the sum of the chair envelope and a clear passage that is required.
>
> [image]
>
> *[irwinseating.com](https://www.irwinseating.com/resources/auditorium-design/common-terminology/back-to-back-spacing)*

---

Recently, I came accross the adverb *a-row* (or *arow*); but it is a rare word.

> Of place: In a row, rank, or line. - *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/10942?redirectedFrom=arow#eid)*

Bonus option:

You can refer to the [I formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_formation) from American football jargon as an analogy.

Comment: It'd be a rum theatre where the rows were back to back! Some sort of avant garde production, I expect.

Comment: *Back-to-back* is indeed the term that inspired this question: it didn't quite feel right as I was describing our theatre reservations to my friend. I often use the term in a temporal context (in place of "immediately after one another"), but in a spatial context it's hard to not imagine the rows facing in opposite directions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one could describe the position of theatre seats behind and in front of a row as being **parallel**.

I found a [math problem](http://openstudy.com/updates/506b027ee4b0e78f215dc492) which uses exactly this expression

> The seats in a theater are arranged in **parallel rows** that form a
>   rectangular region. The number of seats in each row of the theater is
>   16 fewer than the number of rows. How many seats are in each row of a
>   theater that has 1,161 seats

And if you click on the link you'll see an image of [parallel rows of trees](http://www.banffcentre.ca/mountainculture/photo/competition/2005/winners/stoll_patrick.asp).

Comment: Tandem as suggested by one user, reminded me of parallel parking.

Comment: Hm, I hadn't thought of this before. It's an interesting choice and will work in some situations, although it doesn't cover the neighbour-neighbour relationship (e.g. the front and the back row are just as parallel to each other as are rows 9 and 10)

Comment: @sebastian_k  Nothing is stopping you from saying: "the parallel front row" or "the parallel front row". And as for theatre row seats that are *stacked* that sounds as if the seats are placed one on top of the other.

Answer (score 1):

**Appose/Apposite** may indicate spatial proximity.

> place (something) in proximity to or juxtaposition with something
>   else. "the specimen was apposed to X-ray film"

(source: Google)

Also

[image]

from `The London encyclopaedia (Vol 2)`

Comment: I don't see the difference to *adjacent*: as it says in your scan, it means "near or side by side", which is specifically not what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

*Abutting* should fit in this case. *Juxtaposed* may also work.

Comment: Abutting is an interesting choice, but I don't think it's any more specific than adjacent. Juxtaposed carries the notion that the objects were *placed* next to each other to achieve some effect (like contrasting them).